# Rabbitvcs "Unable to connect to a repository" Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn, timeout, rabbitvcs

I am using Ubuntu 17 and installed Rabbitvcs. When I want to execute update or commit commands, sometimes I encounter with

```
"Error while performing action: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://argesrv:3289/svn/Master/Fire/Projects'
Error running context: Timeout on connection".
```

However sometimes those commands can be completed successfully. I checked the server is working correctly and tried with tortoisesvn on windows in same computer, there is no problem about this issue.

Also, there is one more problem with rabbitvcs : Sometimes rabbitvcs menus doesn't appear on nautilus but after a while they appears automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Because of checkout directory disk name has space character, this problem has occured sometimes. When I changed the name the problem was gone.